# Woocommerce Variable Products not adding to the Cart

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi Everyone i am using a woocommerce website. I have added different products on my website. Some of them are single and some of them are variable. Single products are working fine. Now the issue is when i open up a variable product and tries to add into the cart i am getting an error "Please choose product options…" although i already selected an option of that product. When i open up the console i found this error

```
ReferenceError: wp is not defined


...=!1,j=!1,k=c.find(".reset_variations"),l=wp.template("variation-template"),m=wp....
```

The file referencing to this error is add-to-cart-variation.min.js which is located inside the woocommerce plugin folder. I have searched allot and tried different things but could not find out the result. I have also tried disabling all the plugins and but error still remain. Please Help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you can apply a simple jquery fix:

Add the below code in function.php

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) {

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woocommerce_jquery_cookie_script' );

function woocommerce_jquery_cookie_script() {

    // deregister script
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-cookie' ); 

    $suffix = defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ? '' : '.min';

    wp_register_script( 'jquery-cookie', plugins_url( 'jquery_cookie' . $suffix . '.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '1.3.1', true );



}

}
```

and the 2 js file can be download from the below link:

https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/200746747/woocommerce-jquery-cookie-fix.zip

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply where to add these  two files inside the js folder?? and where in code to add the link of those files???

Comment: The js file has to be added into your plugins  folder ie woocommerce/assets/js/jquery-cookie/ folder, no need to add any link.
Or you can directly extract and upload the whole folder in your wp-content/plugins folder. Then login to your admin panel , find it in the plugins list and activate this as normal plugins. Thats all!!

Comment: Expert
I have added the plugin but it is still giving the same error and variable products not added into the cart